# Accessing double from .txt file

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file that looks like:

```
(0.781860352, -11.6927013, 7.20992613)  
(0.364501476, -9.41256046, 6.87873077)  
(0.394773483, -7.85253429, 6.90275288)
```

I need a code to access each double from each line individually. I am having troubles solving this problem. Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

So, like I said, I am accessing each double from each line using the suggestion by Kerrek SB, then I store these values into the components of a vector, then I access each component and perform an operation (say multiply them together), and store the result into an array; finally I add the contents of the array.
Anyway, here is the code:

```
int main() {

    //=============================
    //Initial Declarations
    //=============================

Vector3 r(0,0,0);
int num = 0 , i;
string line;
char c, d1, d2, d3, d4;
double v1, v2, v3 , b[num];

   //=============================
   //Counting Lines in File
   //=============================

ifstream is;
is.open ("data.txt");
while (is.good())
{
c = is.get();
if (c=='\n')num++;
}
is.close();
cout<<"Number of lines in file is "<<num<<endl;

   //=============================
   //Getting Data
   //=============================

ifstream infile("data.txt");

for (line ,i=0 ; getline(infile, line), i<=num-1;i++ )
{

    istringstream iss(line);

    if (!((iss >> d1 >> v1 >> d2 >> v2 >> d3 >> v3 >> d4 >> ws) &&
          iss.get() == EOF                                           &&
          d1 == '(' && d2 == ',' && d3 == ',' && d4 == ')'))
    {

    }

    // Placing data in vector
    r[0] = v1;
    r[1] = v2;
    r[2] = v3;

    //Placing data from vector into array
    b[i] = r[0]*r[1]*r[2];


}

  // Adding contents of array
  valarray <double> bfinal (b,num);
  double b_final = bfinal.sum();


cout<< b[0] << "," << b[1] << ", " << b_final << endl;
return 0;
```

}

The code works (actually it is not adding the contents of the array correctly) , but it seems a little crude. I feel that it could be simplified and/or made more concise. Any ideas?

Comment: This is pretty basic. What have you tried?

Comment: With your edit, this might fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard C++ idiom:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ifstream infile("data.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    char d1, d2, d3, d4;
    double v1, v2, v3;
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    if (!((iss >> d1 >> v1 >> d2 >> v2 >> d3 >> v3 >> d4 >> std::ws) &&
          iss.get() == EOF                                           &&
          d1 == '(' && d2 == ',' && d3 == ',' && d4 == ')'))
    {
        // error parsing "line"
        std::cerr << "Sorry, could not parse '" << line << "'. Skipping.\n";
        continue;
    }

    std::cout << "You said: " << v1 << ", " << v2 << ", and " << v3 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I can't help but snicker a little Kerrek. +1.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: How so? Because it's paste+rep? :-) I normally don't like being cheap, but there are *so many* alleged C++ answers on this site that teach wrong stuff that I'd rather spell this out redundantly one more time :-S

Comment: That too. The funnies of sophistication vs. expectation is an extra bonus. E.g. will OP put this in a proper context, or assume script style parsing.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!
I'll show the context in which this is being used once I work it out. Thanks again.

Comment: You're missing an `else`